# Python. Replace every second "**" with </b> in a string

Tags: python, string

I am trying to parse a Markdown string to an HTML format and struggle to find a solution to replace every second occurence of `**` with `</b>`.

Basicly, I want to write a function that would get a Makdown string as input and output HMTL string.

input: `** Hello!** everyone! **This should be HTML string**`

output: `** Hello!</b> everyone! **This should be HTML string</b>`

At the second step I am planning to use `str.replace()` function and substitute remaining `**` with `<b>`

Would be gratefull for any suggestions!

Comment: You can use [`pandoc`](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html) for conversion between most text formats: `pandoc --standalone -o website.html input.md`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*planning to use str.replace()*

Then you might harness optional (third) argument accepted by this function - number of replacement, following way:

```
txt = '** Hello!** everyone! **This should be HTML string**'
closing = False
while '**' in txt:
    txt = txt.replace('**','</b>' if closing else '<b>',1)
    closing = not closing
print(txt)
```

Output:

```
<b> Hello!</b> everyone! <b>This should be HTML string</b>
```

Nonetheless I suggest using ready tools for dealing with markdown if possible.

Comment: Great idea with setting a closing counter!

Answer (score 4):

Using a markdown library is the way to go, but if you're wanting to do this yourself without a third party library, then regular expressions will make your job easier. These allow you to do find and replaces that match a pattern, In your case you are going to want to start by searching for the regex pattern

`\*\*(.*?)\*\*`

> Asteriks have to be escaped, so this looks for 2 asteriks

> Followed by a parenthetical group. The parenthetical group tells us we want to capture the contents inside of it to reference later on

> Then the `.*` Tells us to match an unlimited number of characters. `.` being any character and `*` being unlimited. The `?` at the end tells us to be non-greedy, so we stop as soon as possible.

And replacing it with

`<b> \1 </b>`

> The `\1` will reference what was in the parenthesis above. If there were more parenthesis you would reference the next set of parenthesis with `\2` and then `\3` and so on.

```
import re

replaced_str = re.compile('\*\*(.*?)\*\*', '<b> \1 </b>', your_string)
```

---

Alternatively you could search for the position of the first occurance of `**`, and then look for the next occurrence of `**` and use that info to do your replacement.

```
s = '** Hello!** everyone! **This should be an HTML string**'
while True:
    pos1 = s.find('**')
    pos2 = pos1 + s[pos1+2:].find('**')

    if pos1 >= 0 and pos2 > pos1:
        s = s[:pos1] + '<b>' + s[pos1+2:pos2+2] + '</b>' + s[pos2+4:]
    else:
        break;

print(s)
```

Comment: Thank you! I start getting the idea of how re.sub() works. I would go for a markdown library, but I need only this feature and wanted to try to implement it myself.

Answer (score 3):

I would implement a counter for the "**" substring (would make it go through the string and look for * and check if there is one more next to it) , and then if(counter % 2 == 0) replace.

Hope this helps, am new here.

Comment: Thank you for the idea! I think this is the most optimal solution and requires only one read of a string.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution with regex

```py
import re
text = "** Hello!** everyone! **This should be HTML string**"

p = re.compile(r"\*\*(.*?)\*\*")

result = re.sub(p, r"<b>\1<b/>", text)

"""
result: '<b> Hello!</b> everyone! <b>This should be HTML string</b>'
"""
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking that you are new to stackoverflow, i would always suggest, do research from net and try to come up with some solution, if you can't do still then u always can ask here

It can easily be done like this

```
    import re
    test_str= '** Hello!** everyone! **This should be HTML string**'
    pattern='**'
    res = [i for i in range(len(test_str)) if test_str.startswith(pattern, i)] 
    res
    for i,pos in enumerate(res):    
        if i%2==0:
            test_str = test_str[:pos] + '<b>' + test_str[pos+3:]
        else: 
            test_str = test_str[:pos] + '</b>' + test_str[pos+4:]
```

Comment: Hi! Yes, I am still new here. I searched to the solution first but couldn't find any that could be suitable for me. Thanks for all ideas!

Answer (score 0):

As Faruk Imamovic proposed earlier I think here is the most optimal solution to the problem.

```
opening = True
pos = 0
res = []
while pos < len(text):
    if text[pos] == "*" and pos < len(text)-1 and text[pos+1] == "*":
        res.append('<b>' if opening else '</b>')
        opening = not opening
        pos += 2
    else:
        res.append(text[pos])
        pos += 1
return ''.join(res)
```